# Xampp. Apache server can't start because api-ms-win-localization-|1-1-0.dll file is missing

Tags: apache, xampp

I installed Xampp 7.3.1 version but whenever i tries to start Apache Server, an error message pop ups that api-ms-win-localization-|1-1-0.dll file is missing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just need to download it from : https://www.dll-files.com/api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-1-0.dll.html and then copy to C:\Windows\System32

Should work after reboot but i think this dll is made by microsoft for windows 10 so probably you are using a version of xampp not compatible with windows 7.

So my suggestion is to try the 5.6 version of xampp for compatible reasons.